# Where did I go wrong in simplifying this code fragment of reversing a singly linked list?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, data-structures

I found a solution on the CareerCup for reversing a singly linked list:

```
void reverse(node n, node prev) 
{
    if (n == null) { head = prev; return; }

    reverse(n.next, n);
    n.next = prev;
}

call reverse (head, null);
```

Which is good to understand and study.If the original list is "1->2->3->4->5", the reversed output will be "5->4->3->2->1".

I am trying to simplifying this solution a bit by using only one parameter, which is the current Node where are working on:

```
void reverse2(Node n)
{
      if(n.next==null){ head = n;return; }

      reverse2(n.next);
      n=n.next.next;
}

call reverse2(head)
```

Maybe you may already tell, the result is not correct, after the method finishes, the modified remains "1->2->3->4->5".

I was confused at first, after thought for a while, I think my fault is as this line:

```
n=n.next.next;
```

in which I was planning to make the next node point back to current node, however, in my current recursion, I am working on the node "n" it self, I wasn't changing anything of this current node n, thus the resulting list is not changed at all.

I am not 100% convinced by myself, could experts offer some guidance? Thanks.

Comment: One up for explicitly stating what you are trying to achieve. Choose an appropriate place to turn to. For coding, expecially improvements, codereview seems a better fit. The algorithm could be: if the list got a tail, reverse that and append `head`. You might consider checking for an empty list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with you algorithm is that it changes nothing in the original data structure.
The original algorithm did this:

```
n.next = prev;
```

which actually reversed one node. You only call:

```
n.next = prev;
```

Which simply changes a parameter of the method, but does nothing else.

I doubt you could solve this problem with a recursion method that takes only one parameter, because after modifying the current node N(i) you need to move on to the next node N(i+1), and that next node should be made to point to N(i). So the next call should know both about N(i) and N(i+1).

Answer (score 0):

First thought,

`n=n.next.next;` why are you changing the entire node as such??

To reverse the linked list isn't it only required to change the `next` attribute?

It should have been something like

`n.next.next = n`

consider when `n` points to `4` in `1->2->3->4->5`

now we have `4.next = 5` and `5.next = null` initially

on excecution it would be like

`4.next.next` => `5.next` = 4

```
1->2->3->4->5---
         ^------|
```